# How do you declare a C# variable into an HTML type variable?

Tags: c#, vb.net, paypal

What's the C# equivalent of

so you can use it for web forms in PayPal API integration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have any decalaration of any C# variable in ASP.NET like a label or a text box type and in order for html or the client side of your web to be able to read what is on that decaration of the C# variable that you have declared this can do:

```
input type="hidden" name="name_type" value='textbox1.Text'
```

Answer (score 1):

<% string name; %> ?

Answer (score 1):

Just use

```
<% string name; %>
```

Is that what you mean?